# Return an array on parsing an error to a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get a final output such as this from a function

```
[{'visible': false},null,null,null,null,{'visible': false}]
```

This is basically a list of columns that I need hidden. So I need to write a function to which if I parse a list of columns that should be visible, it should return me an array such as above. Therefore this is what I am trying to do and I am able to get this working also, however I would like to know whether this is the best and optimal way to do this?

Please request your help. Apologize for some typos, this is my first post.

```
// array of columns to be shown
var arr = ["last_name", "phone", "email", "address"];
toggleVis(arr);

function toggleVis(arr) {
  //list of all the columns.
  arr_columns = ["name", "last_name", "phone", "email", "address", "company"];
  arrayLength = arr.length;
  arr_columnsLength = arr_columns.length;
  var arr_new = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr_columnsLength; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < arrayLength; j++) {
      if (arr_columns[i] == arr[j]) {
        arr_new[i] = "null";
        break;
      } else {
        arr_new[i] = "{'visibilty:false'}";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you should ask this question over at [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Your code seems fine, aside from the fact that you need to return an object not a string , like this: `arr_new[i] = {visibilty: false};`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly your code seems fine overall. The only issues I notice is that you should `return` the new array in your function, and you should use an object and `null` respectively instead of strings when the column name is not found in the array:

```
arr_new[i] = { visibilty: false };
```

That being said you can make the code more succinct by using `indexOf` instead of a second `for` loop to check if the column name exists in the passed array, something like this:

```
function toggleVis(arr) {
    var arr_columns = ["name", "last_name", "phone", "email", "address", "company"];
    var arr_new = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr_columns.length; i++) {
        var col = arr_columns[i];
        arr_new[i] = arr.indexOf(col) != -1 ? null : { visibilty: false };
    }
    return arr_new;
}
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/e3d7snvk/4/)

This can be made shorter still using the `map()` method of the array, but note this is not supported in older browsers (IE8 and lower)

```
function toggleVis(arr) {
    var arr_columns = ["name", "last_name", "phone", "email", "address", "company"];    
    return arr_columns.map(function(col) {
        return arr.indexOf(col) != -1 ? null : { visibilty: false };
    })
}
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/e3d7snvk/5/)

Comment: Why are you returning the string "null" instead of the null value itself?

Comment: Because I'm an idiot and I forgot to update those values too :) Thanks

Comment: Oh I didn't notice that was what OP did - thought there must be some reason. Cool